# Looking for a guide to USB ports - and how to trouble-shoot when things stop working

Tags: raspbian, usb, troubleshooting

Having recently had problems when connecting different devices to my Pi over USB I am looking for a guide (link to) that explains in more detail what goes on in the OS when devices are plugged in to a Pi (4 in my case) and how to trouble shoot and fix when a device stops communicating when a new device is connected.

Comment: not Raspberry Pi specific ... more Linux specific

Comment: If you have one device plugged in and plugging a second disconnects the first it'll most likely be lack of power. When you plug in a new device there's a power surge as the new device is connected which if big enough will cause other connected devices to disconnect and they may not reconnect automatically. What power supply are you using and what devices are you plugging in?

Comment: You can get the source code and go through that then you will know exactly what is happening until it is updated.

Comment: @rohtua What power supply are you using 3 amp USB wallwart made for Pi4
and what devices are you plugging in. USB GNSS dongle - very little power drain + an Icom IC7300 transceiver which does not draw power from USB

Comment: @ Gil - What source code are you referring to and how do I get it?

Comment: @forestDM OK so the power supply itself should be fine then. Its the initial spike in power draw that I think is causing your issue not necessarily what the device needs to run. Your transceiver may be externally powered but it will still draw some power from USB. The way to test would be to plug a passive USB hub into the pi and connect your devices to that. If it works then it's a power issue.

Comment: @forestDM Plugging a hub in basically gets rid of the initial spike of connecting a device as the pi will send max power to the hub so it can use it to power thing plugged into it, so plugging into the hub shouldn't cause any spikes on the pi. Normally I'd suggest a powered hub but if the transceiver has an external supply that shouldn't be necessary unless you want to start plugging in even more devices.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a powered USB wall wart, because if your Pi is disconnecting, that's probably, like 95% sure, why.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi is using linux, you should be able to go the appropriate distro and download source. Raspbian itself contains 22,544 source packages in its main repository, with 67,417 files to download if you want all the source code. This link will guide to the correct place. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315389/how-to-download-a-whole-raspbian-source-code Have you tried a lower impedance power supply to see if that is the problem? Check how much current the devices you are connecting and be sure the Pi can supply that with a little to spare.